# Unexpected Token in React/Redux export

Tags: react-native, redux

Working on my first React Native app (and new to Redux as well). I keep getting the error: "Unexpected token auth" that points to the last line of my auth.js reducer. I'm using Nuclide on Atom for editing with ESLinter to help out. Any thoughts on either (1) what my problem is? Or (2) how do I get Nuclide Diagnostics to provide more information on my error?

```
const defaultState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  token: '',
  client: '',
  uid: '',
  spinner: false
};

const auth = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoggedIn: true,
        token: action.token,
        client: action.client,
        uid: action.uid,
        spinner: false
      });
    case 'LOGOUT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoggedIn: false,
        email: '',
        password: '',
        spinner: false
      });
    case 'LOAD_SPINNER':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        spinner: true,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  };
};

export auth
```

Comment: `export { auth };`

Comment: @SterlingArcher - not the first time the bracket use has goofed me up. Have a good blog post you can direct me to for when to/not to use them in this context?

Comment: Absolutely, it took me a while to learn the changes by heart, but the [MDN on export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) has a great example section

Comment: This is not an Atom-related question, no need to use the `atom-editor` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got Unexpected token auth because of your export. Use `export default auth;`